# Apache/wsgi/django configuration

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

We have two django applications running on the same server that interact with an API that uses oauth. They function as expected, communicating with each other, when run under the django development server. However, when deployed using apache/wsgi they don't work together.

(To be more specific, one application is an instance of the Indivo server; the other one is a custom application that interacts with Indivo.)

What is the best way to trouble shoot this?

Comment: Post your wsgi and apache files.

Comment: Can you post your apache VirtualHost config?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Django instances are working by themselves first.  For example, one app could be started under Apache, and the other using `./manage.py runserver`.  Reverse which one is running using Apache and verify that all works as expected.

Use the Apache error logs to look for errors such as failed requests.

Since one of your apps appears to implement a web API, use something like the [Google Chrome Postman App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to exercise the site from a web browser.

Learn how to use the [Django logging framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) to log information about your apps as they execute.